# Mean and Median Calculations

Tags: probability, data-analysis

A group of 20 has a mean = 85 and median = 80. A different group of 30 has a mean = 75 and median = 72. Now, what is the mean of and median for the entire group of 50?

Comment: Found this question on other sites: [here](http://www.urch.com/forums/gre-math/32092-mean-median.html); [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090225000303AAoHjf5); [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070913061358AAfd9OO); [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/group-20-values-mean-85-median-80-different-group-30-values-mean-75-median-72-mean-50-valu-q1372318).

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration on the answer from response, in case you didn't see weighted averaging before.

So you have $(x_i)_{i=1}^{20}, (y_i)_{i=1}^{30}$ with $\frac{1}{20} \sum_{i=1}^{20} x_i = 85$ and $\frac{1}{30} \sum_{i=1}^{30} y_i = 75$.

Thus, $\sum x_i = 20 \cdot 85$ and $\sum y_i = 30 \cdot 75$ hence total average is
$$
\frac{\sum x_i + \sum y_i}{50} = \frac{20 \cdot 85 + 30 \cdot 75}{50} = 79.
$$

**EDIT** Not sure what to do with the weighted median. To tell exactly, you would need the entire numer range, since it's the middle value. The only thing you can guarantee is that at least half the numbers will be $\geq 72$ and at least half the numbers will be $\leq 85$, so the median $m$ is guaranteed to satisfy $72 \leq m \leq 85$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the idea of a weighted mean.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @O.L. Why not? Searching Google for weighted mean should point the OP in the right direction.

Comment: I agree, but this should better be a comment. That's why your answer was automatically recognized by the system as a low quality post.

Comment: I disagree with the automaton!